# How to time travel to end of animation using React Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, gsap

I'm trying to test a component which change *state* after a TweenMax animation. Everything's fine on browser, but I cannot understand how to write a test for it.

The problem is **Jest** doesn't wait for the animation to complete, therefore *state* doesn't change.

I also tried with [jest.runAllTicks()](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestrunallticks) and [jest.runAllTimers()](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestrunalltimers)

Here some code that would eventually simulate what I'm working on:

#### Component

```js
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { done: false };
        this.p;
    }

    componentDiDMount() {
        TweenMax.to(ReactDOM.findDOMNOde(this.p), 1, { 
            onComplete: () => {
                this.setState({ done: true })
            }
        })
    }

    renderMessage() {
        if (this.state.done) {
            return "Hello World";
        } else {
            return "Loading...";
        }
    }

    render () {
        return <p ref={p => this.p = p}>{this.renderMessage()}</p>;
    }       
}
```

#### Test (basic structure)

```js
describe("test",()=>{
    it("works", ()=>{
        const component = mount(<HelloWorld />);
        // ...wait some time (or pretend to)
        expect(component.find(p).text()).toEqual("Hello World");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Digging into **Jest** documentation I've found that you can specify a `done` parameter which will force the test to wait until `done()` is called.

This way it's possible to set a timeout and wait for the animation to complete.

See [Jest callbacks documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#callbacks)

```js
describe("test",() => {
    it("works", done => {
        const component = mount(<HelloWorld />);
        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(component.find(p).text()).toEqual("Hello World");
            done();
        }, 1100);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can trigger it with:

```
const element = document.getElementById('yourElement');
fireEvent.animationEnd(element);
```